# Why Google Maps API directionsService does not show the optimal route?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm new to Google Maps Javascript API and doing some basic things. I want to show a day trip route of Yellowstone National Park. The start point is West Thumb Geyser Basin, end point is Norris Geyser Basin, as the code showing below (saved as a html file).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
function init() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng({lat: 44.427963, lng: -110.5906437}),// Yellowstone National Park
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
    directionsService.route({
        origin: {lat: 44.4170394, lng: -110.5740972}, // West Thumb Geyser Basin,
        destination: {lat: 44.7262344, lng: -110.7217907}, // Norris Geyser Basin,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    }, function(response, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <font size=2><b>Yellowstone National Parks</b></font>
  <div id=googleMap style="width:1100px;height:800px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But the route returned is not an optimal one.
[Please see the returned route here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xo3E6.jpg)

Seems it's a Google Maps JavaScript API bug? Any idea/thought? Thanks in advance.

Updated code. another funny thing. Without optimizedWaypoints, it's working fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
function init() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng({lat: 44.427963, lng: -110.5906437}),// Yellowstone National Park
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

   var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
   var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
   directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
   calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
}
function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
    var wayPoints = [{ location: {lat: 44.4604826, lng: -110.8303263}, stopover: true }, { location: {lat: 44.525086, lng: -110.840378}, stopover: true }]; // Old Faithful Geyser and Grand Prismatic Spring
    directionsService.route({
        origin: {lat: 44.4170394, lng: -110.5740972}, // West Thumb Geyser Basin,
        destination: {lat: 44.7262344, lng: -110.7217907}, // Norris Geyser Basin,
        waypoints: wayPoints,
        //optimizeWaypoints: true,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    }, function(response, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <font size=2><b>Yellowstone National Parks</b></font>
  <div id=googleMap style="width:1100px;height:800px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not going to be able to optimize the order of the waypoints (you only have one waypoint).  The `optimizeWaypoints` option only rearranges the waypoints, it won't change the start or the destination.

from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints):

> By default, the Directions service calculates a route through the provided waypoints in their given order. Optionally, you may pass optimizeWaypoints: true within the DirectionsRequest to allow the Directions service to optimize the provided route by rearranging the waypoints in a more efficient order. (This optimization is an application of the Travelling Salesman Problem.) All waypoints must be stopovers for the Directions service to optimize their route.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Actually I just removed one waypoint which is 'Grand Prismatic Spring' from the above code. You can see it in the picture. Even after I added that one more waypoint, same result.

Comment: Please update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **that demonstrates the issue**.

Comment: Hi geocodezip, per request I've created a simple html for easy troubleshooting. Also, let's forget the waypoints first, say only origin and destination, according to Google Maps API doc, the default route should be an optimal one, but apparently it's not. This is my original test. Because of this, then later I added waypoints (Old Faithful and Grand Prismatic Spring) and tried to force it show the optimal one, but didn't work either.

Comment: Completely different question.

Comment: I would expect that is a data problem, the routing engine doesn't think it is allowed to turn left out of West Thumb Geyser Basin, so it turns right, but that road is closed in the winter, so it does a U-turn when it can.  [If I move the coordinates to the intersection, it goes the short(er) way](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/fmffr59v/).

Comment: Hmm, that's funny. Also, you can try my updated code above, another funny thing. if without optimizedWaypoints, it's working fine. otherwise no.

Comment: The name of the option is `optimizeWaypoints`, check your javascript console...  `InvalidValueError: unknown property optimizedWaypoints`

Comment: I changed the origin to the intersection, but it still returns the longer way. Also, if I just want to show the shortest way, no matter what condition of the traffic/weather/road close, etc. what should I do? Thanks again.

Comment: Your origin is on the wrong side of the road at the intersection to go that direction ([updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmffr59v/4/)).  Google' s routing engine really thinks that road is divided apparently.